# OpenVPN not listening on port

Tags: server, openvpn

I just set up an OpenVPN server on a VPS but sadly I can't connect to it.
When I made a portscan I found that my custom 11940 port where openvpn should listen is closed. The default 1194 port is also closed, the only other related port open (status: filtered) is the 445 tcp port.

Here are the messages I get if I start openvpn manually:

```
hugo@nepomuk:~$ sudo openvpn --config  /etc/openvpn/server.conf -verb 6
Fri Aug  3 16:42:27 2012 OpenVPN 2.2.1 i686-linux-gnu [SSL] [LZO2] [EPOLL] [PKCS11]     [eurephia] [MH] [PF_INET6] [IPv6 payload 20110424-2 (2.2RC2)] built on Mar 30 2012
Fri Aug  3 16:42:27 2012 NOTE: OpenVPN 2.1 requires '--script-security 2' or higher to call user-defined scripts or executables
Fri Aug  3 16:42:27 2012 Diffie-Hellman initialized with 2048 bit key
Fri Aug  3 16:42:27 2012 TLS-Auth MTU parms [ L:1542 D:138 EF:38 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Fri Aug  3 16:42:27 2012 Socket Buffers: R=[163840->131072] S=[163840->131072]
Fri Aug  3 16:42:27 2012 ROUTE default_gateway=37.247.49.1
Fri Aug  3 16:42:27 2012 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Fri Aug  3 16:42:27 2012 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Fri Aug  3 16:42:27 2012 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Fri Aug  3 16:42:27 2012 /sbin/ifconfig tun0 192.168.42.1 pointopoint 192.168.42.2 mtu 1500
Fri Aug  3 16:42:27 2012 /sbin/route add -net 192.168.42.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw     192.168.42.2
Fri Aug  3 16:42:27 2012 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1542 D:1450 EF:42 EB:135 ET:0 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Fri Aug  3 16:42:27 2012 UDPv4 link local (bound): [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:11940
Fri Aug  3 16:42:27 2012 UDPv4 link remote: [undef]
Fri Aug  3 16:42:27 2012 MULTI: multi_init called, r=256 v=256
Fri Aug  3 16:42:27 2012 IFCONFIG POOL: base=192.168.42.4 size=62, ipv6=0
Fri Aug  3 16:42:27 2012 IFCONFIG POOL LIST
Fri Aug  3 16:42:27 2012 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

What about ROUTE default_gateway=37.247.49.1, this line is 100% wrong since the ip has nothing to do with this server.

Also netstate lists openvpn:

```
hugo@nepomuk:~$ sudo netstat -uapn | grep openvpn
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11940         0.0.0.0:*                           1314/openvpn
```

Thanks for any tips on how to procede!